# Android RecyclerView remove item animation bug

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I'm trying to implement a ToDo list that contains a list and some other views below it on the activity page.

I am using a `LinearLayout` for the entire page and a `RecyclerView` for the list, alongside other views below the `RecyclerView` (`ImageView`, `Buttons`...etc.)

Here's my final view hierarchy:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <TextView />
    <RecyclerView />
    <Button />
    <EditText />
    <ImageView />
</LinearLayout>
```

---

I have implemented the `RecyclerView` where I can add and remove items. 
I am using a `LinearLayoutManager` without specifying an `ItemAnimator` so `DefaultItemAnimator` is used.

Adding items to the list works as expected. My problem is that the page **doesn't animate well when I *remove* an item** from the `RecyclerView` (by removing it from the dataset first then using `RecyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemRemoved`).

What happens is that the entire page snaps first to adapt to the new `RecyclerView` height, and then the `RecyclerView` item remove animation completes, which makes the behavior of the page look weird since all the views below the `RecyclerView` snap up while the deleted item fades out but hasn't lost its height yet, then the remaining `RecyclerView` items (below the deleted item) scroll up, looking like they're sliding up from under a wall.

I tried to look for solutions on the web and couldn't find anything to solve my problem.

I have found [this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36117070/recyclerview-remove-animation-bug) describing the same problem. Please refer to it in case my explanation wasn't clear enough.

Anyone encountering the same issue? Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: so you want to remove animation when item changes right?

Comment: Instead of using notifyDataSetChanged(), use notifyItemRemoved(). NotifyDataSetChanged rebuilds the entire set of data in the RecyclerView, so all rows are redrawn. Whereas notifyItemRemoved() or notifyItemRangeChanged() will only refresh the items that were changed, so the jerky motion will dissappear.

Comment: @Divyesh I don't want to remove the animation, I just want the whole page to animate nicely when I remove an item from the RecyclerView. By that I mean I want the page to wait for the RecyclerView item animation to be done before it translates.

Comment: @Rachit I am using notifyItemRemoved, I mentioned that clearly in my question.

Comment: @Rachit no, I think you misread it. All good though. Any suggestions on how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. In my situation just this line helped:

```
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. What worked is giving the height of RecyclerView in DP instead of `wrap_content` as in my case, the number of items can change.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one and check if it is working as your expectation:

```
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new MyAnim());


public static class MyAnim extends RecyclerView.ItemAnimator {
        @Override
        public boolean animateDisappearance(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull ItemHolderInfo preLayoutInfo, @Nullable ItemHolderInfo postLayoutInfo) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean animateAppearance(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @Nullable ItemHolderInfo preLayoutInfo, @NonNull ItemHolderInfo postLayoutInfo) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean animatePersistence(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull ItemHolderInfo preLayoutInfo, @NonNull ItemHolderInfo postLayoutInfo) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean animateChange(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder oldHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder newHolder, @NonNull ItemHolderInfo preLayoutInfo, @NonNull ItemHolderInfo postLayoutInfo) {
            final float prevAlpha = ViewCompat.getAlpha(oldHolder.itemView);

            ViewCompat.setAlpha(oldHolder.itemView, prevAlpha);

            ViewCompat.setAlpha(newHolder.itemView, 0);

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void runPendingAnimations() {

        }

        @Override
        public void endAnimation(RecyclerView.ViewHolder item) {

        }

        @Override
        public void endAnimations() {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean isRunning() {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That didn't work. The problem is not with the animation of the RecyclerView items themselves, the problem is how the page is handling all the other items below the RecyclerView ... the second i delete an item all the views below the RecyclerView snap to adapt to the new RecyclerView calculated height (after item deletion) BEFORE the remove animation of the item is finished.

Answer (score 1):

Create subclass of `RecyclerView` and override `onTouchEvent` method like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    if (findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY()) == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(e);
}
```

Also, don't use `wrap_content` as `RecyclerView` height/width depending on your orientation.

This way `RecyclerView` has fixed size and does not cut off items while removing them. Manipulation of `onTouchEvent` method assures that part of `RecyclerView` without items does not consumes click events and sends them to parent view of `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the height of your recyclerview or the containers that hold it to: "match_parent". Worked like a cahrm for me.

source: https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/recyclerview-supported-wrap-content-not-quite-f04a942ce624